# The Google Earth plugin refuses to load on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, google-earth

I can't quite believe that there isn't a solution to this available on the web - there seem a lot of people having the problem but no solutions I could find.

The site http://www.google.com/earth/explore/products/plugin.html says

> "Good news - you already have the Google Earth Plug-in installed"

however in the box on the left-hand side it says

> "There was a problem with the Google Earth Plugin"

and suggests restarting the browser and re-installing the plugin.  I've tried both of these but am still getting this error.

I've tried this in both Safari 5.1.2 and Firefox 3.0.1 (yes I know this needs to be upgraded :) )

Any tips of where I should look in the logs to investigate the problem ?

**Edit** : @First - the entries from the Console are

```
30/12/2011 09:08:12 [0x0-0x151151].com.apple.Safari[4327]   NP_Init called
30/12/2011 09:08:13 PluginProcess[4342] Earth plugin chosen models: cg:0 ca:1 ica:0 cocoa:1
30/12/2011 09:08:13 [0x0-0x151151].com.apple.Safari[4327]   2011-12-30 09:08:13.028 PluginProcess[4342:903] Earth plugin chosen models: cg:0 ca:1 ica:0 cocoa:1
30/12/2011 09:08:18 [0x0-0x151151].com.apple.Safari[4327]   Intrinsic Alchemy v3.4 Beta-0930 (Static/Release)
30/12/2011 09:08:18 [0x0-0x151151].com.apple.Safari[4327]   Built by keyhole-build on Fri Sep 30 00:00:00 2011
30/12/2011 09:08:21 [0x0-0x151151].com.apple.Safari[4327]   Chrome IO thread reporting for duty. 
30/12/2011 09:08:21 [0x0-0x151151].com.apple.Safari[4327]   GENetworkAccessManager::GENetworkAccessManager() 
30/12/2011 09:08:23 [0x0-0x151151].com.apple.Safari[4327]   INFO: Using OpenGL Context.
30/12/2011 09:08:42 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[125]  Inspector: UNREGISTERING: bootstrap_register() unknown error code (1103)
```

**Edit** : Seems to be the same problem as https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/earth/problems-and-errors/0zn5gShzFh8

Comment: If you look in Console Application (under Utilities/Console) are there any errors in there?